# How to put an image from a local drive into a cfdocument file?

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument

This will show me the image in a browser:

```
<cfset myImage=ImageNew("d:\UploadedDocuments\thumbnails\1487862_page_1.jpg")>
<cfimage source="#myImage#" action="writeToBrowser">
```

But if I use the same code inside of a .pdf file, it generates a small red x. Is this not possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the image is already on the drive you don't need CFIMAGE here. You can embed it like so:

```
<img src="file:///d:\mysite\images\myimage.jpg" width="50" height="60">
```

You could also use an HTTP Path to it as well - store it at a location accessible by your web server through real or virtual directories use the `<img>` tag like you normally would.

This post on [cfdocument and SSL](http://mkruger.cfwebtools.com/index.cfm/2006/5/29/cfdocument.ssl) and this suplimental post on [using the file system with cfdocument](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2006/5/30/cfdocument.file) should help you sort it out.